# Rake task to update specific products in db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, task, spree

Hi all I've got a database full of products and I need to schedule a rake task to run every week. 
I'm not exactly sure how to code the rake task. An example would be I have a product with id=1 name="testname" description="description" sku="198" price=12.99
I need to upload a csv with name="testname" and update the price to 13.99 while obviously keeping the id intact. 
This is what I've tried so far but its not complete if anyone could help that would be great.

```
require 'csv'
desc "Updates Products inside an ActiveRecord table"
task :update_prods, [:filename] => :environment do
    products = Spree::Product.all
    CSV.foreach('update_prods.csv', :headers => true) do |row|
    Spree::Product.update!(row.to_hash)
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a gist of how we imported products from Shopify to Spree which could give you some ideas on how to go about this https://gist.github.com/dgross881/b4f1ac96bafa2e29be7f.

```js
def update_products

  puts 'Updating Products...'
  require 'csv'
  products_csv = File.read(Rails.root.join('lib/assets/products_list.csv'))
  products = CSV.parse(products_csv, headers: true)

  products.each_with_index do |row, index|
    Rails.logger.info { [#{index + 1}..#{products.length}] Updating product: #{row['title']} }
    product = Spree::Product.find!(row['id'])
    update_product = product.update_attributes(name: row['title'], description:row['description'],
    meta_title: row['seo_title'], meta_description: row['seo_description'],
    meta_keywords: "#{row['handle']}, #{row['title']}, the Squirrelz",
    available_on: Time.zone.now, price: row['price'],
    shipping_category: Spree::ShippingCategory.find_by!(name: 'Shipping'))

    update_product.tag_list = row['tags']
    update_product.slug = row['handle']
    update_product.save!
  end
  Rails.logger.info { "Finished Updating Products" }
end

def update_variants
  puts 'updating Variants...'
  require 'csv'
  products_variants_csv =File.read(Rails.root.join('lib/assets/variants_list.csv'))

  products_variants = CSV.parse(products_variants_csv, headers: true)

  products_variants.each_with_index do |row, index|
    puts "[#{index + 1}..#{products_variants.length}] Adding Variant (#{row['sku']} to Product: #{Spree::Product.find_by!(slug: row['handle']).name})"
    variant = Spree::Variant.find_by!(sku: row['sku']
    update_variant = variant.update_attributes!(sku: row['sku'], stock_items_count: row['qty'], cost_price: row['price'], weight: row['weight']

    unless row['option1'].blank?
      variant.option_values << Spree::OptionValue.find_by!(name: row['option1'])
    end
    unless row['option2'].blank?
      variant.option_values << Spree::OptionValue.find_by!(name: row['option2'])
    end
    variant.save!
  end
  puts 'Updated Variants'
end
```